# iAd interstitial not working after first time

Tags: ios, iad, interstitial

I programmed an app such that when you press a button, it will call the iAd `requestInterstitialAdPresentation()` function.

The first time I do this, it works normally. However, after I close the Ad view, and I press the button again, another ad will not appear. I even turned on the unlimited Ad presentation option in the developer settings in the iPhone.

**Why does another ad not appear? Is there a time you need to wait to present the next ad?**

Answer (score 0):

A new ad only is requested after the first ad unloads. You'll have to wait some time before a new ad is loaded into your system after the first ad unloads.